# Does a http response parser exist in C#?

Tags: c#, html, json, httpwebrequest, response

```
{"sentences":[{"trans":"událost","orig":"event","translit":"","src_translit":""}],"dict":[{"pos":"podstatné jméno","terms":["událost","případ","příhoda","soutěž","sportovní disciplína"],"entry":[{"word":"událost","reverse_translation":["event","occurrence","incident","happening","affair"],"score":0.6872893},{"word":"případ","reverse_translation":["CASE","event","instance","occurrence","episode","subject"],"score":0.017476905},{"word":"příhoda","reverse_translation":["event","incident","episode"],"score":0.0021874912},{"word":"soutěž","reverse_translation":["competition","contest","event"],"score":0.0017304479},{"word":"sportovní disciplína","reverse_translation":["event"],"score":3.2700344e-05}]}],"src":"en","server_time":45}
```

This code I need to parse to own objects (it is google translator response). Does a "http response parser helper" exist in .NET ?

Something like this (google chrome).

[image]

Comment: That's JSON, a widely supported format, but regardless of that, there's probably a library provided by either Google or a third party/open source project that can handle Google Translate responses for you, Google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Json and you can parse it with any json-parser. I'll use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and make use of `dynamic` keyword

This is the [json](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) you want to parse

[image]

```
dynamic json  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

foreach (var sentence in json.sentences)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)sentence.trans);
}
Console.WriteLine();


foreach (var d in json.dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("***TERMS***");
    foreach (var term in d.terms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)term);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("***ENTRY***");
    foreach (var entry in d.entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)entry.word + " , "  + (double)entry.score);
    }
}
```

---

You can also use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) to deserialize your json to type-safe classes. The code would be

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);


public class Sentence
{
    public string trans { get; set; }
    public string orig { get; set; }
    public string translit { get; set; }
    public string src_translit { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public List<string> reverse_translation { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class Dict
{
    public string pos { get; set; }
    public List<string> terms { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Sentence> sentences { get; set; }
    public List<Dict> dict { get; set; }
    public string src { get; set; }
    public int server_time { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data. [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a good JSON (de)serializer for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

That is JSON. Use any C# JSON deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` class, it's built in to .Net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx